# Restrict access to MySQL database, LAN Java desktop app

Tags: java, mysql, database, api, desktop-application

I've looked into some threads but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm used to doing websites and now I want to make a desktop application in Java which connects to a MySQL database.

I will have a server on a LAN running MySQL and a client written in Java to interact with it. The thing is that on websites, code is written on the server side. Therefor, it is easy to give access to certain pages or data to logged in users or users with a certain role.

I have no problems connecting to the database or in Java but I don't know how to restrict the data on the database to logged in users only since the requests are done via the client. I've thought about putting some code on top of the server to restrict the access like an API.

The thing is that an API is quite overkill for the small app I want to make. Is there another software or protocol to use on the serverside to make a user connect first to return data and reject the SQL queries if the person is not connected?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Hey, you're going to have to post some code or at least talk a bit about the libraries or frameworks that you're using. Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: I am just using jdbc to connect to the database, I don't use any frameworks or libraries yet, it's a very simple app so I don't need them.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if I did not understand well, but I think what you want is to restrict data to certain users. Example, that a seller can write data in the sales table while a supervisor can only see them; and a customer can only see product data. If I did not misunderstand you, and what you are looking for is that, you can restrict it directly with a session system and you can add a system based on roles / permissions. You dont need an API, just write your "session" code in your app

Comment: Hey! You got it well the problem is that a session system works well in a website environement but since I have no php code, so no serverside code, I can't assume that the database will be accessed only by the client I wrote. I know it's LAN for the moment, but I don't know if it will change soon, so I'd rather have a good security from the start. Therefor, having some kind of access restriction on the server side.

Comment: Making the code in a Java SE application from the beginning, since it is connected to the database, is a problem, since any decompiler will expose the credentials of your database. Taking security into account, if you still want to make the application in Java SE, it is best to make an API on the server, and make your Java App connect to that API, without ever giving Java SE your BD credentials. You can do the API in Java EE for example, or in PHP if you have knowledge and you will add a security layer that you could not allow if you connect your client app to the BD

Comment: Yes that is my problem, if It gets decompiled, the database is exposed. So I have to go with my first idea and do an API to consume the data on the server? I thought there was a solution like connecting to an auth api and access the data if the user connects to it.

Comment: Another simple solution, although not the best, is that you create a Login based on real MySQL users. Each user would have to create a MySQL user, and he would log in to the app with that username and password, providing the JDBC with the credentials it needs. By creating the user in MySQL you would give the only necessary permissions. Although honestly this is not a professional solution, and would not apply if you have more than 15 or 20 users